# Как убрать статус заказа на странице My order Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, wp-plugin

Есть страничка My order на которой информация о заказе и выглядит она так - 'Order #642 was placed on November 25, 2021 and is currently Completed.' Сам темплейт находится в файле order-details.php, где нет упоминания вызова этого. Дебажил, но не нашел, откуда-то подтягивается хуком.
Задача не выводить или убрать эту строку. Класса не имеет и  задать ей display:none; - нельзя. Может кто сталкивался с этим и знает откуда или как называется хук. Благодарю

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте в `functions.php` [дочерней](https://wp-kama.ru/handbook/theme/child-theme) темы один оператор php:

```
add_filter(
    'woocommerce_order_tracking_status',
    function( $status ) {
        return '';
    }
);
```

И строка `Order #642 was placed...` выводиться не будет.

Answer (score -1):

Эта строка находится в файле tracking.php в самом начале. Я ее просто удалил и проблема решена.

Comment: Модифицировать код плагина нельзя - все ваши правки слетят при обновлении.

Comment: Там для вас эту строку обернули в фильтр `woocommerce_order_tracking_status`.